# What is the motivation behind free groups?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I have started studying free groups but cannot get motivation behind it. I know that a free group $F_A$ over the set $A$ consisting of all combinations or expressions that can be built from the members of $A$.

But why would one want to do such a construction? What is the motivation behind it

Comment: Because every group is the image of a free group, so you every  group $G$ is, up to isomorphism, writable as $F/N$ were $F$ is a free group and $G$ is a normal subgroup.  In this sense, they are the primitive free groups. (It is worth considering what free abelian groups are - they are sums of $\mathbb Z$, and every abelian group is the image of a free abelian group.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, off the top of my head, there are two big things that free groups do for us.

First of all, they give us a nice generalization of the integers under addition--also known as the free group generated by one element. (One could also argue that the trivial group is the free group generated by zero elements.)

Second of all, **every group** is the quotient of a free group! Have you ever seen something like the following before?

$$D_n=\left\langle x,y\mid x^n,y^2,xyxy\right\rangle$$

This is shorthand that says $D_n$ can be obtained by starting with the free group $F$ generated by two elements--$x$ and $y,$ say--letting $N$ be the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ containing each of $x^n,y^2,$ and $xyxy,$ and then forming the quotient group $F/N.$